# string split  and check if parts to prevent errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

lets say that we are studding a url string:

```
http:/domain.com/en/#the-file.html/section-4
```

where i have codified:

```
http:/domain.com/en/#{html file}/{id of the div}-{level}
```

this way i can know by

```
var info = window.location.hash;
var temp = info.split("/");
var url = temp[0];
url = str_replace('#','',url);
var temp1 = temp[1];
temp1 = temp1.split('-');
var seccion = temp1[0];
var nivel = temp1[1];
```

where

```
console.log('url: '+url);
console.log('info: '+nivel);
console.log('seccion: '+seccion);
```

provide me those codified vars

the problem is when, for example, the url is

```
http://domain.com/es/
```

that firebug jumps this error:

```
temp1 is undefined
```

Any idea how to prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `split`, I recommend to use a RegExp, which does not break when multiple slashes or hyphens show up.

The code below will always define the variables `url`, `nivel` and `seccion`. If the hash is not existent, these variables will be an empty string.

```
var info = window.location.hash.match(/^#(.*?)\/(.*?)-(.*)$/),
    url="", nivel="", seccion="";
if (info) {
    url = info[1];
    nivel = info[2];
    seccion = info[3];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `split` method doesn't work by default in Internet Explorer, you'll have to find [a workaround](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split), that's why a RegEx approach would be better. However, if you still want to use split you could use `temp.length` to see how many pieces of string are stored in that variable.

Comment: The error is not caused by an incompability issue in IE, the error is caused by the fact that the size of the array is 0 or 1, if no match is found. Thus, `temp[1]` is `undefined`. Hence, `temp[1].split` throws a ReferenceError.

Comment: @Rob I know, that's why I recommended temp.length, but if he'll use split he should keep in mind that this will break in IE.